# apple LLVM 6.1 error Could not read profile: No such file or directory (after upgrade to XCode 6.4/7.0 beta2)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to compile a Cordova project.
The project was working fine with XCode 6.3 and iOS 8.3 phone.
We upgraded the phone to 8.4 then everything stopped working.
I tried XCode 6.4 - got this error.
I tried XCode 7.0 beta 2 - got this error.
Search on google shows that many have this problem with no solution.
I tried to clean the code, project->build for->generate optimization profile, restart the computer, etc. Noting help.

Comment: So what's the file it cannot find?

Comment: "Could not read profile" as the title says :)

Comment: That's not the name of a file.

Comment: That's all the error code. It didn't say more then that.

Comment: It was a Cordova's problem:
To fix it:
1. Remove both platform and plugins folders.
2. cordova platform add ios
3. Add all your plugins again.
4. Don't forget to select your profile on the project's first tab.
Same steps as when you trying to remove a plugin (never working for iOS).

Answer (score 0):

It was a Cordova's problem: To fix it:

1. Remove both platform and plugins folders.
2. cordova platform add ios
3. Add all your plugins again.
4. Don't forget to select your profile on the project's first tab.

Same steps as when you trying to remove a plugin (never working for iOS).